# Angular Cli add Hash Tag after file name in Prod Build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When i make Build using angular cli then i get the files as

```
inline.b82bfbf37295902d0092.bundle.js
polyfills.b82bfbf37295902d0092.bundle.js
scripts.b82bfbf37295902d0092.bundle.js
styles.b82bfbf37295902d0092.bundle.js
vendo.b82bfbf37295902d0092.bundle.js
main.b82bfbf37295902d0092.bundle.js
```

But i wantthese hash name after name of the bundles like

```
inline.bundle.js?b82bfbf37295902d0092 
polyfills.bundle.js?b82bfbf37295902d0092... like these all the file 
generated.
```

Kindly help how to acheive that

Comment: If you put the hash after the bundle name, won't it defeat the purpose of the hash for cache busting?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are limited in what you can change about filename hashing.  By using the `--output-hashing` flag, you can choose `all, none, media, and bundles`

Comment: Can we write a plugin or loadre for that

Comment: The last time I checked they were not open sourcing the web pack compiler. Not sure if that has changed.